# Uniconta Sales Quotation POST CRUD API

Tags: c#

I am trying to post a sales quotation using [Uniconta CRUD API](https://www.uniconta.com/da/developers-unipedia/api/), I first created the Sales Quotation and then Sales Quotation Line. The Sales Quotation is getting created but it's throwing an error for Sales Quotation Lines as “SetMaster is not called for this class”. This is the code I am using:-

```
    var acc = new DebtorOfferLine();
    var accHeader = new DebtorOffer();

    acc._Item = "8SC-PRO-1";
    acc._LineNumber = 1;
    acc._Price = 100;
    acc._Qty = 1;

    accHeader._DCAccount = "100";
    accHeader._Lines = 1;
    accHeader._YourRef = "TestQuo3";

   capi.SetMaster(acc, accHeader);

  var response = capi.Insert(acc).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first insert accHeader then only you can set it as master to acc.

```
var acc = new DebtorOfferLine();
var accHeader = new DebtorOffer();

acc._Item = "8SC-PRO-1";
acc._LineNumber = 1;
acc._Price = 100;
acc._Qty = 1;

accHeader._DCAccount = "100";
accHeader._Lines = 1;
accHeader._YourRef = "TestQuo3";
var responseOfferInsert = capi.Insert(accHeader).Result;
capi.SetMaster(acc, accHeader);
var response = capi.Insert(acc).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the capi part
when you create the capi you initialize it as var capi = CrudAPI(baseApi); right?
if so you don't need the line setMaster as Uniconta will know all classes apart by the unique tableId in your class

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this `acc.SetMaster(accHeader);` instead.